# What is the purpose of end plates when connecting beams together?

Tags: structural-engineering

[image]

Quite often this kind of arrangement can be seen when beams are connected together. A rectangular plate is welded into a beam, and the plate is bolted to the other beam. I suppose one purpose would be simply that bolting is easier to do in some cases at the site rather than welding the beams together directly at construction site, **but is there any other purpose?**

I remember once hearing this kind of plate refered to as a *moment plate*, but I couldn't really find much information on such a thing. Is there some kind of moment-related purpose for this plate or am I just remembering wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. It is easier to do a weld under the specified heat and approved specs in a shop likely by a robot and get the welds pre approved by the authority in charge as a large batch. As opposed to having to pay a license welder and a authorized weld inspector.

Bolts could be torqued  by automatic torque wrench easily on the job site.

This saves time, money.

Comment: Several different type of attachments are shop welded to facilitate field  bolting of steel beams.

Answer (score 2):

Welding a beam to a column can deform the column at its bending axis.

The axial load on a steel column is determined by multiplying the moment by a bending factor. The bending factor is the area of the cross section divided by the section modulus.

These factors are tabulated in the AISC Manual for the x and y axis.

When a portion of that cross section is modified by welding, the column is no longer as strong.